# Import statement for Venmo iOS SDK in swift for embedded framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, venmo

I am trying to implement the Venmo-iOS-SDK into my app using CocoaPods. Inside my `Podfile`, I have the `use_frameworks!` statement to make all dependencies into embedded frameworks. After running `pod install`, the Venmo-iOS-SDK appears to correctly be installed in CocoaPods, but I cannot figure out what to put at the top of my files as an `import` statement.

The other pods that I have worked with do not have dashes in their name, so I am just able to put `import PodName`. However, `import Venmo-iOS-SDK` triggers a compile time error stating "consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ;".

I have tried all the following statements and none work:

`import Venmo-iOS-SDK`

`import Venmo`

`import VenmoiOSSDK`

`import VenmoSDK`

Does anyone know what to import for this framework in swift, or what the import statement looks like for other pods with a `-` in their name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try the below option

```
import Venmo_iOS_SDK
```